# Css column won't fill row height

Tags: html, css

Wondering if I can get some help here.  In the fiddle I have most of the necessary markup.

http://jsfiddle.net/theDawckta/54z3J/

I cannot figure out how to make the columnItem in column 1 to extend to the bottom of the row.   What I would like to see in column 1 is the green fill up the red row part while leaving the black content the same size.

I think it's impossible, so good luck, I have had enough of this.

Comment: No, no javascript, I know I tagged it as javascript but that was just to pull more people in to look at it :)

Comment: Is it not possible to make the parent `.row` background-color green? (And if necessary add another div with a red background as the footer?)

Comment: Did one of the posts answer your question? If so, please accept the one that was the most correct/helpful. Thanks! (See [How do I ask questions here? in FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).)

Answer (score 2):

I actually cut out quite a bit of your code, so apologies in advance if you needed those extra divs (but it shouldn't be too difficult to add them in later). Also, you may want to test this in IE--I'm not sure what version this cuts out on (but I think it works in IE7+).

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="column">
  <div class="columnItem">
   <p>Content</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="column">
  <div class="columnItem">
   <p>Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="columnItem">
   <p>Content</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
 overflow:hidden;
}
.column {
 float:left;
 width:50%;
 padding-bottom:10000px;
 margin-bottom:-10000px;
}

/* You can remove everything under this comment */
.columnItem {
 padding:10px;
 margin:5px;
 background:blue;
}
.column:nth-of-type(1) {
 background:yellow;
}
.column:nth-of-type(2) {
 background:pink;
}
```

**How it works**

It's really quite simple. Each row hides everything past where the actual content is (with `overflow:hidden;` while each column pushes itself downward 10,000 pixels with `padding-bottom:10000px;`, and then back up again with `margin-bottom:-10000px;`. The number of pixels can be increased or decreased, just make sure it's large enough to fit your content.

P.S. - Anything is possible, the impossible just takes longer. ~ NSA

Answer (score 0):

Omer Ben-Nahum suggested tables, but I'm not sure that is how you want to mark up your content. There really is no way to achieve this effect using CSS, but you can use some workarounds that give the site the appearance that you were able to get it to work. Look into using [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) as an alternative to tables.

Answer (score 0):

bfroh's solution is one i've used several times before, but in general I usually use a background image to emulate situations like this (where the content in one div isn't making it tall enough)

The wrapping container's background image could have the background color for the entire left div and just set that to 'repeat-y'

Dealing with these sort of issues (in my experience) either pretty much entails the hack that bfroh posted or a solution like this.

Hope it helped!

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do it using css, but you can do this via javascript method. 
I wouldn't recommend that because it means that you will have to run the script each time the content changes and I'm not sure you always know when it does.

If this issue is important to you, I suggest you use tables.